# Nef divisors on abelian varieties are pullbacks of ample ones

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, divisors, pullback

It is well known that for any polarization ( that is, ample line bundle) $L$ on an abelian variety $A$, there is an isogeny $\phi\colon A \to B$ to another abelian variety with a principal polarization $M$ such that $\phi^*M=L$.

If instead I take a **nef** but not ample divisor $D$ on $A$, is it always true that $D$ is the pullback of some ample divisor on a quotient of $A$?

Thanks for help!

Comment: No, take a generic degree 0 divisor on an elliptic curve.

Comment: If you work in the complex setting I think the Appel-Humbert theorem should give you essentially what you want (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appell%E2%80%93Humbert_theorem). The only caveat, is that you might have to work "up to translation." Nefness I think corresponds to positive semidefiniteness of the Hermitian form H in the Appell-Humbert theorem. Then the kernel of this form should define a sublattice corresponding to a subcomplex torus. If you quotient by this subtorus, I think it should be straightforward to check that the Hermitian form "descends" and is ample on that quotient torus.

Comment: ... A minor annoyance is that one might not be able to descend the $\alpha$ in the Appell-Humbert theorem (e.g. in @wnx's answer - indeed this is true for "most" strictly nef line bundles with a given $c_1$). However, if you only want up to topological equivalence, i.e. to say that there is a quotient $A\rightarrow B$ such that $D$ is the image of some ample divisor under $\mathrm{NS}(B)\rightarrow \mathrm{NS}(A)$ then you should be okay I think.

Comment: Thinking more algebraically, it seems that the quotient should be taken by (the connected component of) $T(L) = \{ x\in A \,:\, T_x^* L \cong L\}$. Indeed, the restriction of $L$ to $T(L)^\circ$ lies in its $\mathrm{Pic}^0$, so by twisting by an element of $\mathrm{Pic}^0(A)$ one should be able to ensure $L$ trivial on $T(L)^\circ$. Then it descends to the quotient and is ample there (I think finiteness of $T(L)$ will ensure this).

Comment: Thanks to YosemiteStan and PiotrAchinger for their useful comments. Can you write them as an answer, so I can accept them?

Comment: @PiotrAchinger, I don't understand how the divisor descends to quotient and why it should be ample. Also, why $T(L)$ has to be finite? $L$ is not supposed to be ample.